# How to get best selling products by period in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress

I want to show the top selling products in WooCommerce for the last 30 days. Just to show the top sellers overall is no problem with the provided code.

What the code is missing is the part where you get sales in a certain period of time. The meta_query should be the key to do this but I'm not sure how. Any help is appreciated!

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    endwhile;
} else {
    echo __( 'No products found' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this short code for best selling product in Woo commerce.
[best_selling_products] in page edit.

OR

Also add on php file where you want like
do_shortcode('[best_selling_products per_page="12"]');

Comment: Thanks for the answer but here we are still missing the time/period in which the products were bought e.g. last 30 days or last 7 days.

Comment: We are looking for solution that shows products with the time period. e.g. Best Selling products based on sales in last 30 days or 7 days instead of all time

Answer (score -2):

Just Change your code like below

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
        'orderby'   => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' )
);
```

Hope its work.